# Comparing python dictionaries and find diffrence of the two

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So im trying to write a python program that will take 2 .json files compare the contents and display the differences between the two.  So far my program takes user input to select two files and compares the two just fine.  I have hit a wall trying to figure out how to print what the actual differences are between the two files.

my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import json

#get_json() requests user input to select a .json file
#and creates a python dict with the information
def get_json():
    file_name = raw_input("Enter name of JSON File: ")
    with open(file_name) as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        return json_data

#compare_json(x,y) takes 2 dicts, and compairs the contents
#print match if equal, or not a match if there is difrences
def compare_json(x,y):
    for x_values, y_values in zip(x.iteritems(), y.iteritems()):
        if x_values == y_values:
            print 'Match'
        else:
            print 'Not a match'

def main():
    json1 = get_json()
    json2 = get_json()
    compare_json(json1, json2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

example of my .json:

```
{
    "menu": {
        "popup": {
            "menuitem": [
                {
                    "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()",
                    "value": "New"
                },
                {
                    "onclick": "OpenDoc()",
                    "value": "Open"
                },
                {
                    "onclick": "CloseDoc()",
                    "value": "Close"
                }
            ]
        },
        "id": "file",
        "value": "File"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to compare only at the top level, or recursively?

Comment: Or if that's not clear, can you edit your question to add a second json example you want to compare against?

Comment: .. and the expected results, please :)

Comment: Seems as if you should be using Python [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) :)

Comment: I would like to compare recursively.  Of the two files I would like to use the first as a "Master" and compare the second file to the master.  Any values or keys the 2nd has that the master does not I would like to print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that dictionaries are stored in a structure with an internal logical consistency - when you ask for `someDict.items()` and `someOtherDict.items()`, the key-value pairs of elements are computed by the same algorithm. However, due to differences in the keys that may be present in either dictionary, identical keys may not be present in the corresponding index in either list returned by the call to `dict.items()`. As a result, you are much better off checking if a particular key exists in another dictionary, and comparing the associated value in both.

```
def compare_json(x,y):
    for x_key in x:
        if x_key in y and x[x_key] == y[x_key]:
            print 'Match'
        else:
            print 'Not a match'
    if any(k not in x for k in y):
        print 'Not a match'
```

If you want to print out the actual differences:

```
def printDiffs(x,y):
    diff = False
    for x_key in x:
        if x_key not in y:
            diff = True
            print "key %s in x, but not in y" %x_key
        elif x[x_key] != y[x_key]:
            diff = True
            print "key %s in x and in y, but values differ (%s in x and %s in y)" %(x_key, x[x_key], y[x_key])
    if not diff:
        print "both files are identical"
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps alot.  My question I think was worded bad.  I would like to find the differences in the two dictionaries and print what those differences are.

Comment: I understand how to check if the files are similar, but im stuck trying to print the actual differences in the values / keys?

Comment: Thanks again for all the help G4dget.  So im trying my best to follow along with your code.  In the elif, if the key is in both the first file and the second file but have different values it prints which key, then prints the contents of the key in both files using (x[x_key] for the first and y[x_key] for the second).

x[x_key] and y[x_key] both return the entire key, how can I modify those to only display the values with in the key that are different? 

I have been attempting my own variations of it with nothing but errors.

Comment: The code in the `elif` should only print out the values of `x` and `y` that are different for the same key. So for example, if the key is `"menu"`, and the values for this key differ between `x` and `y`, then both the values are printed out, along with the key. The easiest way to modify my code to not print the key itself is to remove the firs `%s` in the `print` and remove `x_key` from `%(x_key, x[x_key], y[x_key])`

Comment: Forsome reason, the code in the elif is printing everything except for the key name.  For example in the above .json, if i changed "Value": "New" to something like "Value": "Old" in the second file.  The elif would print everything in x and y other then the key menu.

Comment: `x_key` is the key (in your example, it could be `"Value"`). `x[x_key]` is the value associated with the `x_key` in `x` (in your example, it could be `"New"`). Similarly, the `y[x_key]` is the value associated with `x_key` in `y` (in your example, it could be `"Old"`). So you should really consider what you want to print and print exactly that

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out the jsondiff library in python. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsondiff/0.1.0

The examples referenced from the site are below.

```
>>> from jsondiff import diff

>>> diff({'a': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
{<insert>: {'b': 2}}

>>> diff({'a': 1, 'b': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
{<update>: {'b': 2}}

>>> diff({'a': 1, 'b': 3}, {'a': 1})
{<delete>: ['b']}

>>> diff(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
{<insert>: [(3, 'd')]}

>>> diff(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'])
{<delete>: [1]}

# Similar items get patched
>>> diff(['a', {'x': 3}, 'c'], ['a', {'x': 3, 'y': 4}, 'c'])
{<update>: [(1, {<insert>: {'y': 4}})]}

# Special handling of sets
>>> diff({'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'a', 'c', 'd'})
{<add>: set(['d']), <discard>: set(['b'])}

# Parse and dump JSON
>>> print diff('["a", "b", "c"]', '["a", "c", "d"]', parse=True, dump=True, indent=2)
{
  "$delete": [
    1
  ],
  "$insert": [
    [
      2,
      "d"
    ]
  ]
}
```