# Rethinkdb Python - Changes: How to return only the field that changed?

Tags: python, rethinkdb

How can I use the changefeed in rethink to receive only the field that changed instead of all the available fields?

If this is not possible, what is the most optimal way python-wise to find the modified field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know before, which fields are going to change you can specify your selection that way with e.g. **pluck/filter**. Otherwise you can't. The changes will be served including the whole document as:

```
{
   "old_val":"{}"
   "new_val":"{}"
}
```

On the topic how to compare those json documents in your changefeed, you will find plenty solutions e.g:

[Comparing python dictionaries and find diffrence of the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297044/comparing-python-dictionaries-and-find-diffrence-of-the-two)